# Method for invoking transaction from another transaction in Hyperledge composer

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

The old version of hyperledger support below method. But newest not

```
const generateReport = getFactory().newTransaction('org.cusat.hospital', 'GenerateReport');
```

While testing in new version shows an error of

```
Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: transaction returned with failure: TypeError: getFactory(...).newTransaction is not a function
```

Please suggest alternative method.

Answer (score 0):

i found one way of invoking transaction from java script. see if this helps.

const TransactionSubmit = require('composer-cli').Transaction.Submit;

let options = {
  card: 'admin@tutorial-network',
  data: '{"$class":"net.biz.digitalPropertyNetwork.RegisterPropertyForSale","transactionId":"TRANSACTION_001","seller":"mae@biznet.org","title":"TITLE_001"}'
};

TransactionSubmit.handler(options);